# Replicate "adb tcpip" copy / restart adbd without root

Tags: android, tcp, adb, logcat

I've researched a lot about adbd and adb. I'd like to replicate the "adb tcpip 5555" command by doing the following:

I open up the adb shell via cmd (I'm using Windows 10 and a Samsung S5 Android 6.0 for testing purposes) and then I enter:

```html
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

Whenever I enter one of those commands, the output (in the next line) is just the command that I just entered and does not give any further information. Checking with

> getprop service.adb.tcp.port

returns 5555 though. The adbd service does not seem to restart however, as entering

> adb connect *ip-of-S5*

results in

> unable to connect to *ip-of-S5*:5555

Pinging works though, so the ip/connection is not a problem. (Just like adb tcpip 5555 works as well.)

In case this helps, here is some further information:

```html
getprop | grep adb

[init.svc.adbd]: [running]
[persist.sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[ro.adb.secure]: [1]
[service.adb.root]: [0]
[service.adb.tcp.port]: [5555]
[sys.usb.config]: [mtp,adb]
[sys.usb.state]: [mtp,adb]
```

Is there any way to get to know how the orginal adb tcpip command works internally? It doesn't need root, so it should be possible to do it manually as well, right?

Thank you very much!

Best regards

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens when you try those commands?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear about it, I was very tired. I added some more information, thank you for asking.

Comment: you are using `adb connect` on your pc (and with an ip address), not within the adb shell? https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/4bc51d1ea48dcd11e1b4db084145c2d0de8ddbdb/adb/services.cpp#L100 it's setting the same property, not sure about the "restarting in tcp mode" part. Doesn't look like it restarts the adbd.

Comment: All of the commands that I listed are executed on my cmd shell on Windows. I exit the shell before I type adb connect (it just gives an error otherwise and it would be counterintuitive, as I would first need a connection via usb/wifi and then enter the shell)
I found the stop/start adbd lines on some forums. However, leaving it out does not work either. Your code sample shows adb_close() at the end of the method. I guess that invokes some sort of stop -> autorestart mechanic. The question is how to do that via the adb shell. (Thank you for your effort by the way!)

Comment: what's the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: I want to understand the adb tcpip command more to imitate it for my own purposes. (And maybe change some things)